# Python decorate methods with variable number of positional args and optional arg

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-decorators

I am writing my first Python (3.4) application using SQLalchemy.  I have several methods which all have a very similar pattern.  They take an optional argument `session` which defaults to `None`.  If `session` is passed, the function uses that session, otherwise it opens and uses a new session.  For example, consider the following method:

```
def _stocks(self, session=None):
    """Return a list of all stocks in database."""
    newsession = False
    if not session:
        newsession = True
        session = self.db.Session()
    stocks = [stock.ticker for stock in session.query(Stock).all()]
    if newsession:
        session.close()
    return stocks
```

So, being new to Python and eager to learn all of its power, I thought this smelt like the perfect time to learn a little something about Python decorators.  So after a lot of reading, like this [this series of blog posts](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=240808) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1594484/4530863) fantastic SO answer, I wrote the following decorator:

```
from functools import wraps

def session_manager(func):
    """
    Manage creation of session for given function.

    If a session is passed to the decorated function, it is simply
    passed through, otherwise a new session is created.  Finally after
    execution of decorated function, the new session (if created) is
    closed/
    """
    @wraps(func)
    def inner(that, session=None, *args, **kwargs):
        newsession = False
        if not session:
            newsession = True
            session = that.db.Session()
        func(that, session, *args, **kwargs)
        if newsession:
            session.close()
        return func(that, session, *args, **kwargs)
    return inner
```

And it seems to work great.  The original method is now reduced to:

```
@session_manager
def _stocks(self, session=None):
    """Return a list of all stocks in database."""
    return [stock.ticker for stock in session.query(Stock).all()]
```

HOWEVER, when I apply the decorator to a function that takes some positional arguments in addition to the optional `session`, I get an error.  So trying to write:

```
@session_manager
def stock_exists(self, ticker, session=None):
    """
    Check for existence of stock in database.

    Args:
        ticker (str): Ticker symbol for a given company's stock.
        session (obj, optional): Database session to use.  If not
            provided, opens, uses and closes a new session.

    Returns:
        bool: True if stock is in database, False otherwise.
    """
    return bool(session.query(Stock)
                .filter_by(ticker=ticker)
                .count()
                )
```

and running like `print(client.manager.stock_exists('AAPL'))` gives an `AttributeError` with the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Code\development\Pynance\pynance.py", line 33, in <module>
    print(client.manager.stock_exists('GPX'))
  File "C:\Code\development\Pynance\pynance\decorators.py", line 24, in inner
    func(that, session, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Code\development\Pynance\pynance\database\database.py", line 186, in stock_exists
    .count()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'query'
[Finished in 0.7s]
```

So I am guessing by the traceback, that I am messing up the order of the arguments, but I can't figure out how to order them properly.  I have functions that I want to decorate that can take 0-3 arguments in addition to the `session`.  Can someone please point out the error in my methodology?

Comment: Pass `session` as a named argument  -- `func(stuff, session=session)`. Also, why do you invoke `func` twice? Lastly, this really seems like there should be a context manager for the `db.session`.

Comment: thanks @jwilner ! invoking the `func` twice was just a misunderstanding on my part on the syntax.  I changed the `func` call to `result = func()` and then return the result.  Yeah, also right about a context manager on the `db.session`.  I had tried to trim a bunch of code out so as to isolate my question better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
def inner(that, session=None, *args, **kwargs):
```

to

```
def inner(that, *args, session=None, **kwargs):
```

and

```
return func(that, session, *args, **kwargs)
```

to

```
return func(that, *args, session=session, **kwargs)
```

It works:

```
def session_manager(func):

    def inner(that, *args, session=None, **kwargs):
        if not session:
            session = object()
        return func(that, *args, session=session, **kwargs)

    return inner


class A():

    @session_manager
    def _stocks(self, session=None):
        print(session)
        return True

    @session_manager
    def stock_exists(self, ticker, session=None):
        print(ticker, session)
        return True

a = A()
a._stocks()
a.stock_exists('ticker')
```

Output:

```
$ python3 test.py
<object object at 0x7f4197810070>
ticker <object object at 0x7f4197810070>
```

When you use `def inner(that, session=None, *args, **kwargs)` any second positional argument (counting `self`) is treated as `session` argument. So when you call `manager.stock_exists('AAPL')` `session` gets value `AAPL`.

Comment: Thanks,  This really helped.  I had a feeling I was just mixing up the order of args.

Answer (score 1):

First thing I noticed was that You are calling decorated function twice

```
@wraps(func)
    def inner(that, session=None, *args, **kwargs):
        newsession = False
        if not session:
            newsession = True
            session = that.db.Session()
        #calling first time
        func(that, session, *args, **kwargs)
        if newsession:
            session.close()
        #calling second time
        return func(that, session, *args, **kwargs)
    return inner
```

During second call session would be already closed.
Also, You don't need to explicitly accept `that` and `session` parameters in decorator function, they are already in `args` and `kwargs`. Take a look at this solution:

```
@wraps(func)
def inner(*args, **kwargs):
    session = None
    if not 'session' in kwargs:
        session = that.db.Session()
        kwargs['session'] = session
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)
    if session:
        session.close()
    return result
return inner
```

You may also want to put session closing code in `finally` block, then You will be sure that it is closed even if decorated function throws an exception

Comment: without explicitly passing `that` in the `inner()` and the `func()`, I get `NameError: name 'that' is not defined`